# Performing multiple Http requests to same endpoint, merge and sort response

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, angular-httpclient

What I'm trying to achieve is to make multiple requests to an api, merge and sort the result and assign it to the this.products$ observable. This mostly works as the code looks now (see below) in that the end result finally turns into a single list.

The fetchIds()-method get the the parameters from a store. sliceToArrays(any[], number) take in the parameter list and split it into smaller parts. The reason I'm doing this is to avoid making the url too long for the GET method this.api.listProducts([],''), since an url query has a maximum character limit that gets hit when there are too many Ids.

The problem I'm facing, except for the gnawing feeling that I'm using this the wrong way, is that I can't get it to sort the merged result; it sorts 2 lists, before combining them, making it look like this [A, B, C, A, B, C] instead of [A, A, B, B, C, C].

```
ngOnInit() {
this.pageSize = 100;

this.products$ = this.fetchIds().pipe(
  mergeMap(ids =>
    forkJoin(this.sliceToArrays(ids, this.pageSize).map(idsList => this.api.listProducts(idsList, 'watchlist'))).pipe(
      mergeMap(products => merge(...products)),
      toArray(),
      map(products => sortBy(products, ['inventoryStatus', 'authorLastFirst']))
))); }

sliceToArrays(input: any[], maxSliceSize: number): any[][] {
const slices = Math.floor((input.length + maxSliceSize - 1) / maxSliceSize);
const collection: any[][] = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= slices; i++) {
  collection.push(input.slice((i - 1) * maxSliceSize, i * maxSliceSize));
}
return collection; }

fetchSkus() {
return this.watchListStore.items.pipe(
  filter(watchlist => watchlist !== null),
  map(watchlist => watchlist.map(i => i.id))
); }
```

Anyone who could point me in the right direction? I've been trying different things for days, but this (angular, typescript, etc) isn't really my area of expertise.

Comment: Why do all of this on the client? Why not on the server?

Comment: I suppose the main reasons were to be ease and flexibility. There already exist good, flexible framework for getting products by ids in the backend, and simply changing the frontend from making 1 call to making X calls seemed better than creating a whole new method in the controller on the server for this specific use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't get it to sort the merged result; it sorts 2 lists, before combining them, making it look like this [A, B, C, A, B, C] instead of [A, A, B, B, C, C].

I think you can flatten your stream a little bit. Also, don't forget the error handling. Maybe something like this:

```
this.products$ = this.fetchids().pipe(
  map(ids => this.sliceToArrays(ids, this.pageSize)),
  switchMap(idLists => combineLatest(...idsList.map(ids => this.api.listProducts(ids, 'watchlist')))),
  map(productLists => productLists.reduce((acc, curr) => ([...acc, ...curr]), [])),
  map(products => products.sort((a, b) => a.inventoryStatus.localCompare(b.inventoryStatus))),
  catchError(error => of([])) // and a nice message to the UI
)
```

When the logic is non-trivial like here, I like to make a human-readable layer, and hide the hacky logic in functions:

```
this.products$ = this.fetchids().pipe(
  map(ids => splitIdsIntoQueriableChunks(ids, this.pageSize)),
  switchMap(idLists => fetchAllProducts(idLists)),
  map(productLists => mergeProducts(productLists)),
  map(products => sortProducts(products)),
  catchError(error => notifyError(error))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, was thinking it could prob. be flattened!

Case is this: I get a list of Ids with fetchIds(). I want to use those Ids to get a list of products and add it to this.products$, which is an Observable<Product[]>. Since the list of Ids can be too long to use in a single GET call (there is a limit of like 2086 characters in the url with query parameters), I want to split the list in to multiple smaller list (the exact number of lists gets calculated inside sliceToArrays()), then make a GET request of each of those lists, merge the responses into one list and sort it in alphabetical order.

Comment: @TomasHjelm I edited my answer, I was not sure combineAll was good that way. Feel free to ping me if you have any questions.

Comment: Omg, I'm so stupid. It actually does work, I forgot I sorted it on 'inventoryStatus' first, and then alphabetically, so it SHOULD look like [A,B,C,A,B,C], only the first ABC are available and the other unavailable...

Thanks for the help though! Your solution looks cleaner, and yea, I'm gonna make it better human-readable now when I know it works =)